# Can anyone identify this plant? (Thessaloniki, Greece)

Tags: identification

I found a bunch of these up on one of the mountains outside town and brought a few back. They're a little wilted now because I took a while to properly replant them, and I haven't removed the dead leaves at the bottom yet, but they seem pretty hardy! [image]

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to see from this picture.
The genus should be *Sedum*, which is very frequent in Europe.

It is a succulent plant, so various species are adapted on very hot climate, but some also on very cold climate, which is also dry (as not as "lack of water, but lack of "liquid water" and dry air).

Give it sun, and cover with some more soil, so that it can form new roots.

The segments are still "fat", so you do no need to water now (risk of rot). Wait few weeks, so that the plant will build new roots.

For final identification, we need to see the flowers. They are often white or yellows (some also red). Some species have larger flower. It is a nice plant for stone garden.

PS: I'm not sure you used the right soil. You should check if Thessaloniki soil is limestone.

Comment: Unhappy Burro tail? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=burro+tail&t=ffsb&iax=images&ia=images A Sedum, but there are lots of them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedum

Comment: @WayfaringStranger: no, I think some wild species, but yes, there are many. With just this photo I do no think we can go much further. But knowing the species should already help a lot on how to care it. When it blooms (and new segments), we may go further on identification.

Comment: Thanks, @GiacomoCatenazzi and @WayfaringStranger! I'll try to keep it dry and sunny and cover it with a bit more soil. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to check if Thessaloniki has limestone soil. I tried googling it, but didn't come up with anything, and I don't know how to do it myself. I have it in some store bought succulent soil, which I don't know the exact composition of either.